# Error 503 - Varnish cache server

Tags: server, virtualbox, localhost

**Note: This website won't let me post images or more than 2 links due to lack of points. The complete message is available with all the screenshots and all the links [here.](https://sites.google.com/site/plumiinstallation/page2)**

I'm on Windows 7, and I have installed the latest stable version of Ubuntu Server inside a VirtualBox virtual machine. Hence, Windows 7 is the host, and Ubuntu Server is the guest computer.

I have followed the instructions for the Quick Installation of Plumi (a mod of Plone) (link to instructions available in full message link).

I thus have the following 7 services running:

- cache
- nginx
- ploneftp
- transcodedaemon
- uwsgi
- worker
- zeo

Because this is Ubuntu Server, I have no way to see localhost from within the guest (because I only have terminal access to Ubuntu Server from outside), or at least that's how it seems.

Therefore, to see the guest's localhost, I'm trying to access localhost from a browser on my host.

I configured VirtualBox > Network Settings to NAT as below...

```
Screenshot available in full message link.
```

...and added Port-Forwarding as below...

```
Screenshot available in full message link.
```

...next, when I went to localhost on my host computer, I got this...

```
Screenshot available in full message link.
```

...next, I tried the Bridged Adapter setting in VirtualBox > Network Settings,

```
Screenshot available in full message link.
```

..and when I went to localhost on my host computer, I still got the same **Error 503** message

Apparently this is a very common error reported on the internet. A common proposed solution was to "clear the Varnish cache". One of the proposed solutions on the internet is to run the following command line instruction

```
varnishadm -T 127.0.0.1:6082 url.purge .
```

I tried running this instruction at various places along the directory tree, even in the directory where I can clearly see something called "varnishadm", but I keep getting the following error message:

```
The program 'varnishadm' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install varnish
```

I am attaching the following

- log files from doing "tail -f var/log/*" are available in full message link.
- site.cfg file is available in full message link.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Note: This website won't let me post images or more than 2 links due to lack of points. The complete message is available with all the screenshots [here.](https://sites.google.com/site/plumiinstallation/page2)**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there should be no necessity for you to "View" the localhost from within the Host System.

> Therefore, to see the guest's localhost, I'm trying to access
>   localhost from a browser on my host.

Instead, you can use a "bridged-mode" in the OVM and assign a local ip (or configure it to get one from the same DHCP server where your host system gets.) Thence, you can access it with the same url in your specified port.

Also., I remember configuring Apache to Listen in 8080 and Varnish in 80 with drupal and other php applications. So it would be better if you can check your Varnish as well as nginx's configuration.

Try editing your varnish config in your Terminal by typing,

sudo nano /etc/varnish/default.vcl

It should be something like

> backend default {
>       .host = "127.0.0.1";    .port = "8080"; }

Chances are if you try this port in your host machine browser, it would be up.
If not You can simple try restarting Varnish by

sudo service varnish restart (or start if status is down)

Let me know if this doesnt helps.

Comment: OK, I'm going to take this step-by-step. So I used "Bridged Adapter" in the VirtualBox Network settings. I couldn't see anything there to assign a local ip. After the Ubuntu Server came on, I did "ifconfig" at the command line, and got an inet address of 10.0.2.15 ... is this equivalent to a local ip?

Comment: 1st plz check the "Host" adapter its bridged to. if you use more than 1 ( as do I)

Comment: 1st plz check the "Host" adapter its bridged to. if you use more than 1 ( as do I) Plz bridge it to the correct adapter. 
after booting in, in the Ubuntu terminal try adding the ip address that would be in your Lan. (I am in 192.168.1.0/32 so this would work.) Plz assign appropriately.

sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.16 netmask 255.255.255.0 

And check this by typing ifconfig again.
and use "route" if you need to give gateway (not required for this exercise)

Check the ip address u just assigned from host. before that confirm varnish runs by "sudo service varnish status"